# Efficiently change the EOL character in strings

Tags: java, networking, text, protocols

I am writing a network app for Android.  According to the protocol specification, the end of each line must be a CR/LF combination.  While I have no problem with generating this with my own strings, there are times that I will have to process user input and convert the line end.

It doesn't matter what I store the EOL as internally, as long as it gets sent over the wire as CR/LF; if the easiest way is to change it as it goes to the network, that's OK.

What is an easy and efficient way to ensure that all my network output ends with CR/LF, no matter what my string is in memory?

Comment: Edited to state the question - what's an efficient way to ensure that my output has a specific EOL character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's an efficient way to ensure that my output has a specific EOL character?

Normally when you read lines of text, it doesn't include the original EOL characters

When you write the lines, write the EOL character(s) you want instead of using something like `println`

If you have a String in memory which contains unknown EOL characters you can use

```
s = s.replaceAll("(\r\n|\r|\n)", "\r\n");
```

Comment: For those who, like me, didn't know that alternation (|) is guaranteed to be ordered - it is: ["The Pattern engine performs traditional NFA-based matching with ordered alternation as occurs in Perl 5."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Depending on application, you may want to also add the reversed order `\n\r` to cover _all_ cases. But be sure to put it at the beginning rather than end, e.g. `.replaceAll("(\n\r|\r\n|\r|\n)", "\r\n")`

Comment: @ChadNB Do you know which platform reverses the `\n\r` ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am not aware of a specific platform using LFCR. I was just mentioning it in case one is normalizing input which may be accidentally or maliciously corrupt, such as in a web app form submission. That is why I mentioned: "Depending on application, you may want...to cover all cases."

Comment: @ChadNB Good point, but if it is corrupt, it is more likely to be a mixed combination of standard `\n` plus `\r\n` i.e. it was edited on both systems at different times.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's a very good point as well. I hadn't thought of that. I think my suggestion should still work though. Suppose for example the input `\n\n\r\n\n`. With the original regex, it would be interpreted as LF, LF, CRLF, and LF - 4 EOLs total. In my version it would be interpreted as LF, LFCR, LF, LF - again 4 EOLs, so same result. Only time I think it would be a problem is if it was edited on both *nix and antique Mac. In that case it becomes ambiguous and there is no definitively correct solution.